# Fetching Reddit posts in React using Axios, weird JSON path

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to get the titles of reddit posts from a subreddit in React, using Axios for fetching.

I can fetch the `JSON` from [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ReactJS.json), and would like to get the data of each object (post/comment) separately (so I can show titles, post text and the like in the `render()` part of the component).

Here's the first lines of that JSON, pretty-printed:

```
{
  "kind": "Listing",
  "data": {
    "modhash": "",
    "dist": 27,
    "children": [
      {
        "kind": "t3",
        "data": {
          "approved_at_utc": null,
          "subreddit": "reactjs",
          "selftext": "Previous two threads - [June 2019](https:\/\/www.reddit.com\/r\/reactjs\/comments\/bvxng8\/beginners_thread_easy_questions_june_2019\/) and [May 2019](https:\/\/www.reddit.com\/r\/reactjs\/comments\/bjgval\/beginners_thread_easy_questions_may_2019\/). \n\nGot questions about React or anything else in its ecosystem? Stuck making progress on your app? Ask away! We\u2019re a friendly bunch. \n\nNo question is too simple. \ud83e\udd14\n\n---------------------------------------------\n\n\ud83c\udd98 **Want Help with your Code?** \ud83c\udd98\n\n* **Improve your chances** by putting a minimal example to either [JSFiddle](https:\/\/jsfiddle.net\/Luktwrdm\/) or [Code Sandbox](https:\/\/codesandbox.io\/s\/new). Describe what you want it to do, and things you've tried. Don't just post big blocks of code!\n\n* **Pay it forward!** Answer questions even if there is already an answer - multiple perspectives can be very helpful to beginners. Also there's no quicker way to learn than [being wrong on the Internet](https:\/\/xkcd.com\/386\/). \n\n**Have a question regarding code \/ repository organization?**\n\nIt's most likely answered within this [tweet](https:\/\/twitter.com\/dan_abramov\/status\/1027245759232651270?lang=en).\n\n---------------------------------------------------\n\n**New to React?**\n\n**Check out the sub's sidebar!**\n\n\ud83c\udd93 Here are great, **free** resources! \ud83c\udd93\n\n* [Create React App](https:\/\/facebook.github.io\/create-react-app\/)\n* [Read the **official** Getting Started page](https:\/\/reactjs.org\/docs\/getting-started.html) on the docs.\n* [\/u\/acemarke](https:\/\/www.reddit.com\/u\/acemarke)'s [suggested resources for learning React](http:\/\/blog.isquaredsoftware.com\/2017\/12\/blogged-answers-learn-react\/)\n* [Kent Dodd's Egghead.io course](http:\/\/kcd.im\/beginner-react)\n* [Tyler McGinnis' 2018 Guide](https:\/\/medium.freecodecamp.org\/a-comprehensive-guide-to-react-js-in-2018-ba8bb6975597)\n* [Codecademy's React courses](https:\/\/www.codecademy.com\/catalog\/language\/javascript)\n* [Scrimba's React Course](https:\/\/scrimba.com\/g\/glearnreact)\n* [Robin Wieruch's Road to React](https:\/\/roadtoreact.com)\n\n-----\n\nAny ideas\/suggestions to improve this thread - feel free to comment here!\n\n----\n_Finally, an ongoing thank you to all who post questions and those who answer them. We're a growing community and helping each other only strengthens it!_",
          "author_fullname": "t2_2aun3ozb",
          "saved": false,
          "mod_reason_title": null,
          "gilded": 0,
          "clicked": false,
          "title": "Beginner's Thread \/ Easy Questions (July 2019)",
          "link_flair_richtext": [

          ],
```

Here's my component (without the render part, just what happens after that fetch is complete - i.e. the `componentDidMount()` function):

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs.json`)
    .then (
      res => {
        const posts = res.data.data.children.map(obj => obj.data);
        this.setState({posts});
      }
    );
  }
```

This works perfectly.

My question is - why?

My logic would go - get `res` -> look for `data` -> look for `children` -> look for `data`, then `map()` that `data` object into the `data` object for `posts`.

Instead, what seems to work is - get `res` -> look for `data` -> **look for `data`** -> look for `children`, then do the mapping.

Comment: your ques is, why `res.data.data` (two data keys)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how `axios` parses the response json object. They store it under their own personal `data` key. It just so happens that within the `json` object provided by Reddit, they also have a field called `data` that holds the `children` array you want.

It might be more helpful to name your variables like so:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs.json`)
       .then((res) => {
          const redditJson = res.data
          const posts = redditJson.data.children.map(obj => obj.data)
          this.setState({
              posts: posts
          })
       })
  }
```